# Has there ever been a successful 'bail-out' during an airliner test flight?

Tags: accidents, flight-testing

Has there ever been an instance of a crew having to 'bail out' during a test flight of a commercial style aircraft (I.e Airbus, Boeing etc)?

I know that test flight crews often wear orange suits, parachutes during preliminary flight in case there is an issue.

Comment: related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/how-does-this-test-flight-escape-aparatus-work

Comment: The concorde prototype (it's at Duxford in the UK) had an escape door in it, my understanding is that nobody ever would expect to successfully use it. Having seen it myself I would agree it's pretty unlikely.

Comment: After seeing the cockpit escape hatch (http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/which-external-instruments-are-visible-on-the-a350s-nose-section/8203#8203) in an Airbus picture, I wonder if it has been tested? I would imagine that anything on an aircraft as (potentially) important (life-saving) as an escape hatch would need to be tested beyond simulation.

Comment: @CGCampbell They've obviously been tested on the ground to check that a person can get through them wearing whatever the crew will be wearing. But the only way to test them "live" would be to fit one to a plane that's known to work and then get somebody to jump through it. That would be extremely dangerous and wouldn't necessarily tell you much, since it's a different plane with different airflow. My guess is they're not tested "live": they probably just do their best and hope it won't be needed. A sensibly designed, untested escape hatch is way better than none at all.

Comment: @CGCampbell: The escape hatch in _that_ picture looks like a standard cockpit emergency exit that is fitted to production aircraft and intended to be used on the ground only e.g. if the cockpit door is jammed after emergency landing. The additional escape hatch on prototypes intended for parachuting is on the bottom side.

Comment: Exiting via the top escape hatch is rather dangerous - you might very well hit the tail.

Comment: On the Boeing 727 there is the famous DB Cooper incident.  Not aircrew, and survival is unknown, but it's a datapoint. ;)

Comment: @JasonR That was a great read.. thanks!

Comment: Can such planes be exited via the cargo bay hatches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this experiment to observe a deliberate airliner crash

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Boeing_727_crash_experiment

the crew exited in flight down the tail stairs...